# Is it possible to use swagger codegen to generate a client for .Net4.0?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, swagger-codegen

I'm new to C# and Swagger and I was wondering if it's possible to use swagger codegen to generate a client for .Net4.0? After having a look at the CSharpClientCodegen class I managed to get swagger codegen generate a client for .Net3.5 but build.bat fails with `src\IO.Swagger\Model\User.cs(53,193): error CS0241: default parameter specifiers are not permitted.` Now I got stuck and don't know what else I could try.

For my project I need to use .Net4.0 and therefore I have the need to generate a .Net4.0 client. Is there any way to get such a client generated?

Greetings, Stefi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, Swagger Codegen C# client generator supports the following framework:

```
targetFramework
    The target .NET framework version. (Default: v4.5)
        v3.5 - .NET Framework 3.5 compatible
        v4.5 - .NET Framework 4.5+ compatible
        v5.0 - .NET Standard 1.3 compatible
        uwp - Universal Windows Platform (IMPORTANT: this will be decommissioned and replaced by v5.0)
```

(Ref: java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar config-help -l csharp)

If you're looking for a particular framework or .net version that is not yet supported at the moment, please open a ticket via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new and we'll look into it.

UPDATE: On May 2018, about 50 top contributors and template creators of Swagger Codegen decided to fork Swagger Codegen to maintain a community-driven version called [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator). Please refer to the [Q&A](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/qna.md) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I opened a ticket on Github. For everbody else who might come accross this: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/6596

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [NSwag](https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag), it will generate CSharp and Typescript client code for you.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I already had a look at NSwag but try to keep the list of additional tools / libraries as small as possible. From my point of view it should be possible to generate a .Net4.0 client with the swagger-codegen.jar. Or is there a certain reason why one should use NSwag (besides the situation when you have a ASP.Net Api to get a client generated from)? :-)

Comment: Just tried it with NSwag but couldn't find a way to state that the client should be build for .Net4.0 :-( Any hint on that?

Comment: @Stoffelchen You have to play around with https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwagStudio to get the desired config. NSwag supports up to .NET Core 2 so I'm not sure what else you mean

Answer (score 0):

Updating this answer because while William Cheng's answer was correct the output from swagger-codegen-cli is now outdated and v4.0 is now supported.

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar config-help -l csharp
```

Will output the following now (as of version 3.0.22)

```
targetFramework
    The target .NET framework version. (Default: v4.5)
        v3.5 - .NET Framework 3.5 compatible
        v4.0 - .NET Framework 4.0 compatible
        v4.5 - .NET Framework 4.5+ compatible
        v5.0 - .NET Standard 1.3 compatible
        uwp - Universal Windows Platform (IMPORTANT: this will be decommissioned and replaced by v5.0)
```